# pymodbus package import error - modulenotfound

Tags: python-3.x, modulenotfounderror, pymodbus

Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspian (most current as of 02/09/2023), Python 3.9.2. Installed Pymodbus with `pip3 install -U pymodbus[twisted]`  (detail: it said twisted was not available).

When I run my code in Python I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymodbus.server.asynchronous'` on the line `from pymodbus.server.asynchronous import StartTcpServer, StopServer`.

Any idea as why it is not working? Same process used to work in 2021 with Python 3.7.

Installed Pymodbus from this command `pip3 install -U pymodbus[twisted]`

EDIT: I read the official page for Pymodbus https://pypi.org/project/pymodbus/ which says that the current version of it is compatible with Python 3.8+ , and the old versions of it were compatible with up to Python 3.7 (which was the version I was using). Could this be breaking the code and giving me the error i'm getting?

EDIT 2: Full traceback

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/mohm-lhf/Program2.py", line 11, in <module>
    from communication import MODBUS
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/shiboken2/files.dir/shibokensupport/__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/mohm-lhf/communication.py", line 8, in <module>
    import modbus_server as server
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/shiboken2/files.dir/shibokensupport/__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/mohm-lhf/modbus_server.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pymodbus.server.asynchronous import StartTcpServer, StopServer
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/shiboken2/files.dir/shibokensupport/__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymodbus.server.asynchronous'
```

Comment: Can you attach the full traceback?

Comment: Done SpazaM, traceback on the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twisted is removed from [3.0.0dev5](https://github.com/pymodbus-dev/pymodbus/releases/tag/v3.0.0dev5), and I can see that you used this `import` line in your code:

```
from pymodbus.server.asynchronous import StartTcpServer, StopServer
```

This is an old implementation working only for 2.5.3<, there is a new way of implementing an async server - [check here](https://github.com/pymodbus-dev/pymodbus/blob/dev/examples/server_async.py) the example.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that helped. Is there any documentation about that? I mean, an example code is ok but a bit more explanation would be more helpful.

Comment: From what I can see, the [documentation](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html) is the only thing they have to offer. If I helped, appreciate it if you can mark the answer as resolved.